# Insert record to multiple tables which are dependent on each other in c# with Transaction

Tags: c#

I am new to C#

I got two tables:
Employee table ( E_id (PK), first_name, Last_name, Address, DOB, Email )
BankDetail table ( Id (PK), bank_name, Acc_no, E_id (FK) )

Both PKs are auto increment.

Now the problem is, I need to insert data both of the tables simultaneously.  but if the employee Id (E-id) generates during incretion then how I will get that value to put in to BankDetails E_id on the same operation. I also need to use Transaction here for database integrity.

Can anyone explain in very easy way please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at TransactionScope http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The best way I think to achieve this is to wrap your operation inside a stored procedure. You can use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) to get the ID of the previously added record and [TRY-CATCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) to ensure that both insert queries are executed or none at all.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY

   INSERT INTO Employee (first_name, Last_name, Address, DOB, Email)
   VALUES (@fname, @lame, ... etc)

   -- Get the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope
   SET @E_Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

   INSERT INTO BankDetail(bank_name, Acc_no, E_id)
   VALUES (@bname, @ano, @E_id)

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;            
END CATCH;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Dear #Giorgos thanks a lot mate. let me implement this then i may get back to you if you are comfortable to answer bit more.

Comment: @Cloud Ok, no problem. Please note that the above code is suitable for Sql Server. It is better to put operations like these in the db server, rather than trying to accomplish them in C#